# fabric up the network failed

Tags: docker

When I execute the command `./byfn.sh -m up`

The following error occurs:

> Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
>
> Continue? [Y/n] y
>
> proceeding ...
>
> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:4243. Is the docker daemon running?.
>
> See 'docker run --help'.
>
> LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0-rc1
>
> DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=
>
> =================== WARNING ===================
>
> Local fabric binaries and docker images are
>
> out of  sync. This may cause problems.
>
> ===============================================
>
> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Mac.
>
> ERROR !!!! Unable to start network

Answer (score 2):

1. ## Fetch bootstrap.sh from fabric repository using

   curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh -o ./scripts/bootstrap.sh
2. ## Change file mode to executable

   chmod +x ./scripts/bootstrap.sh
3. ## Download binaries and docker images

   ./scripts/bootstrap.sh [version]

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-sync the docker images first:

```
fabric-samples/scripts$ sudo ./fabric-preload.sh
```

Make sure you have the right version set in the script. In your case `VERSION=1.1.0-rc1`

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the permission, try

`sudo ./byfn.sh -m up`

Answer (score 0):

This message caused from your Docker Daemon since it not started yet, please start your docker first.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use diiferent versions of the Fabric and the Docker images.

Answer (score 0):

you can update the yum and docker's version，use：yum update，and url of docker：https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/

Comment: You imply that docker isn't installed, that's quite an assumption, please verify assumptions in the question's comment section.